# Wifi, Bluetooth neither wired ethernet aren't working on my Dell Inspiron-7420

Tags: wireless, network-manager, bluetooth, ethernet

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS a month back alongside windows 8. All was good until a week ago when I was trying to shut down my computer via Ubuntu; it froze. So I forcefully shut it down by pressing the power button for a lengthy time. The next day when I turned on my computer Ubuntu was not detecting any wireless connection. Bluetooth was there though. I tried fixing the problem by skimming through lots of blogs but I guess I made things even worse since now even bluetooth is gone. The key on the keyboard that used to turn wifi on and off stopped working.

Things in windows are good. There is no problem there at all with anything.

Please help as I am totally novice to the world of Ubuntu. Although I have learned a lot through reading I still don´t think that I can fix this problem by myself.

Answer (score 0):

This may work as a temporary fix (I also have an Inspiron and this fix works for my bluetooth, which seems to randomly go off sometimes):

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Enter `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset`

About the wifi, make sure "enable wireless" is checked (have missed that myself in the past; my old computer had a hard switch, and once i sat around for 20 min. trying to figure out why my wifi wasn't working).